# How to make config class from application.properties in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have two questions.

First, I tested db connection in spring-boot like below.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OracleConnectionTest {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OracleConnectionTest.class);

    private static final String DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl";
    private static final String USER = "user1";
    private static final String PW = "user1";

    @Test
    public void testConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PW)) {
            LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(connection));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }
}
```

But I wanted to separate DB information into application.properties file(resources/application.properties). So I need to make JdbcConfig file(java bean) like below(with test code).

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public class JdbcConfig {
    @Value("${driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JdbcConfig[" +
                "driverClassName=" + driverClassName
                + ", url=" + url
                + ", username=" + username
                + ", password=" + password
                + "]";
    }
}
```

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JdbcConfig.class})
public class OracleConnectionTest {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OracleConnectionTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private JdbcConfig jdbcConfig;

    @Test
    public void testConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LOGGER.info("Test: {}", jdbcConfig.toString());

        Class.forName(jdbcConfig.getDriverClassName());

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConfig.getUrl(), jdbcConfig.getUsername(), jdbcConfig.getPassword())) {
            LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(connection));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }
}
```

However, I encountered `NullPointerException(JdbcConfig)` when running `testConnection()`. So I have to modify JdbcConfig class like this.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class JdbcConfig {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JdbcConfig[" +
                "driverClassName=" + driverClassName
                + ", url=" + url
                + ", username=" + username
                + ", password=" + password
                + "]";
    }
}
```

I don't understand why `@Configuration` & `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations don't apply.

Second, I thought spring-boot would automatically create `DataSource(javax.sql.DataSource)` by reading `application.properties`. For example, my friend success test without creating DataSource bean(class). But I encountered an error like below.

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ds'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available
```

So I have to create DataSource bean. I don't know why my friend's code automatically works without creating bean(DataSource) unlike me. My code below.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DataSourceConfig.class)
public class DataSourceTest {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataSourceTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource ds;  // DataSource & DriverManagerDataSource

    @Test
    public void testConnection() throws Exception {
        try (Connection con = ds.getConnection()) {
            LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(con));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@Import(JdbcConfig.class)
public class DataSourceConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataSourceConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(JdbcConfig jdbcConfig) {
        LOGGER.debug("Test: {}", jdbcConfig.toString());
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(jdbcConfig.getDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcConfig.getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(jdbcConfig.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(jdbcConfig.getPassword());
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading my long text.

---

add a property file(application.properties)

```
# JSP
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp

# language setting
spring.http.encoding.charset = UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled = true
spring.http.encoding.force = true

# Database Info
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username = user1
spring.datasource.password = user1
```

Comment: `I don't understand why @Configuration & @ConfigurationProperties annotations don't apply.` - Did you miss `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` when you used `@Configuration` & `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations?

Comment: Your `application.properties` file might be missing some keys or you haven't provided the valcues correctly. Spring boot automatically create the Datasource bean from the values provided in the property file. If it finds everything in the classpath. Please provide your application.properties file or else check if you have provided everything correctly.

Comment: yes, I missed `@PropertySource` when using `@Configuration` & `@ConfigurationProperties`. I thought these are used separately([ex](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)). Maybe I misunderstood these annotations..

Comment: thank you for comment. I added my application.properties file. I have to check this file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
```

+

`@EnableConfigurationProperties(YourPropertiesClass.class)` on any configuration class

If you are using Spring Boot 2.+ then even this is redundant
See [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#configurationproperties-scanning) for more

It is needed to add `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` now

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using Spring Boot 2.2.6. Maybe this is reason why `@ConfigurationProperties` does not work. Well, the reason why these config annotations are redundant is because of the auto-configuration? or using other annotations?

Comment: More detailed explanation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#configurationproperties-scanning. You have to add @ConfigurationPropertiesScan